# Linq to select same datatype from multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What I'm trying to achieve is a list of strings from multiple tables.  I currently have a simple database structure with a ParentTable with 2 child tables, (Let's say Child1 & Child2).
Both Child1 & Child2 have a column of type nvarchar(50) called Name.  Currently, I can perform multiple queries to achieve a single list of strings:

```
var myList = new List<string>();
myList.AddRange(Child1.Select(c1 => c1.Name));
myList.AddRange(Child2.Select(c2 => c2.Name));
```

OR

```
var myList = new List<string>();
myList.AddRange(ParentTable.SelectMany(x => x.Child1.Select (c1 => c1.Name)));
myList.AddRange(ParentTable.SelectMany(x => x.Child2.Select (c2 => c2.Name)));
```

My ultimate question is whether or not it is possible to consolidate it down into 1 query, even if it means using the Parent table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `Concat` operator:

```
var results = Child1.Select(c1 => c1.Name)
              .Concat(Child2.Select(c2 => c2.Name)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Union` operator and it also removes the duplicates for you:

```
var q = Child1.Select(c1 => c1.Name).Union(Child2.Select(c2 => c.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: That's assuming he *wants* to remove duplicates.  He wasn't removing duplicates before, and he wants functionally equivalent code that just does a single round trip to the DB instead of two.

Comment: @Servy that's right in the case he wants to keep the duplicates, obviously `Concat` is same as `Union All`, thanks for mentioning.